# how to put label of horizontal colorbar below colorbar in matplotlib?

Tags: colorbar

[image]

Hi

I managed to get colorbar under the contours and make it horizontal. However the label of this horizontal colorbar is above it. Is it possible to put the label under the horizontal colorbar? For example, in my plot, the label is called required injection pressure. Can I move it under the colorbar?  Thanks

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
# create an axes on the right side of ax. The width of cax will be 5%
# of ax and the padding between cax and ax will be fixed at 0.05 inch.
ax = plt.gca()
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="5%", pad=0.3)  #'right'

#orientation="horizontal" to move colorbar to bottom instead of on the right
cb=plt.colorbar(m, boundaries=np.arange(vmin, vmax+v_step, v_step),orientation="horizontal",cax=cax)
```